# PHP Inserting row into MySQL - Which method is more appropriate?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, row

There are two most notable ways of inserting a row into a MySQL database using PHP:

1. Create a single PHP file which uses a loop to detect whether `isset($_POST['submit_button']` has been submitted, and if the form has not been submitted then display the HTML form. If the form has been submitted, during the loop insert the data into the MySQL table.
2. Create the HTML form on `page1.html` and when the form is submitted parse the data and insert into the MySQL table on `page2.php`.

Both methods work perfectly fine - however, based on your own opinion, is one better than the other (such as security, maintainability etc...)?

Comment: These are *not* the "most notable" ways, and both methods are less than ideal. There are many [PHP frameworks](http://phpframeworks.com) out there, **learn one and use it**.

Comment: @meagar would you say using a framework is essentially based on saving time for coding?

Comment: @TronCraze Partially, it saves time both up-front and in the long run. You'll write less code, so there is less work up-front and less work in maintaining the code. As a pleasant side-effect, your code will be nicely organized and (if you use the framework properly) more secure. Overall it's less about spending less time, and more about writing better software.

Comment: @meagar thanks so much, will take a look at some frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

Given the choice, I would choose neither.  Instead I would opt for the [Post-Redirect-Get (PRG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, by which the form posts to a secondary page which *only* processes the input, but produces no output itself.  Upon successful or unsuccessful completion of processing, the script redirects to a final page, which may be the original form page to display messages, errors, or request resubmission.

Typically, session variables would be used to pass information back to the final redirection point, whether that means values from `$_POST` to repopulate a form, or success/error codes.

This goes a long way toward solving issues with accidental form resubmission via the browser back button.

Your second method of posting to a different page is like an incomplete form of PRG.

Comment: Quick question, if we were to use scenario 1 but had an internal loop to check whether a row with the form data already existed - wouldn't that necessarily be similar to PRG (apart from the fact that MySQL would need to search the database to find the duplicates?)

Comment: @TronCraze No, it wouldn't be too similar, as it would be missing the key component of the PRG - form processing code never resides in the same script as form display code.

Answer (score 0):

I can say that from a usability standpoint, I prefer the first method, because it allows you to create sticky forms, i.e.

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" value="<?php echo $_POST['foo']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases where it is practical, I'd try to get away from having a second user pageload at all. `page1.html` submits via AJAX to a web service provided via `page2.php`. And yes, there are many cases where this isn't appropriate, but the most common patterns I can think of where the form handler is simply inserting rows into a database are well suited to an AJAX submit.